# Div in LI causes extra row before content

Tags: html, css

If I have the following HTML. Why does the content of the li drop down a line?

I am looking for an explanation of the behaviour and how to fix

```html
<html>
    <body>    
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <div style='width:65%;float:left;'>
                            Left Text
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:35%;float:left;font-style: italic;">
                            Right Text
                        </div>
                        <div style='clear:both;'></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>left</td><td>right</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: the snippets above just inherit from the browsers stylesheet

Comment: Div is a block element,add a class to it and in your Css do  .inlinedivClass{display:inline-block;}   On my phone now so can't test, let me know if it works

Comment: Hi @Billy thanks for responding but that doesn't solve my issue. When you get back to your PC it would be great if you could look into it again. Thanks

Comment: Won't be back till tomorrow, sorry. Could you change the div for a span, or does it have to be a div?

Comment: Do they have to be floated left, that's what's doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DIV's are set as `display: block` by default, therefore it does not stay in the same line as the LI..

If you set it as `display: inline;` it will force it to stay in the same line

```html
<html>
        <body>    
            <div>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <div style="display: inline;">
                            <div style='width:65%;float:left;'>
                                Left Text
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:35%;float:left;font-style: italic;">
                                Right Text
                            </div>
                            <div style='clear:both;'></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit:**

as Billy said there is an issue with the floats, but changing them to inline-block adds another issue, the margin [look at this explanation](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Adding a SPAN instead of a div won't solve the issue, because the difference is that the SPAN is `display: inline;` by default, (the same as we have now with the DIV)

```html
<html>
<body>    
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <div style="display: inline;">
                    <div style="width:65%;display: inline-block;margin-right: -2px;">Left Text</div>
                    <div style="width:35%;display: inline-block;font-style: italic;margin-left: -2px;">Right Text</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Are you able to supply working changes to my snippets in your response

Comment: I don't know how to add it to my anwser, if you can add it I'll add my change

Comment: sorry, just updated so we can run the code snippet. but looking at that it still moves the content down a line below the 1

Comment: You are correct, but if you add it using the console it works...
other solution is to use `display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle`, but it's too much, I'll investigate a little bit more

Comment: thanks @miguelmpn for spending the time. That link is a good read

Comment: Can someone have a look at this? why does this https://jsfiddle.net/hbuw3nn5/1/ works and adding `display: inline;` on CSS does not (this is what lead me to the first post incorrectly)